# javascript shorthand for python a[1:]

Tags: javascript, python, string, substring

So I have a string in javascript

```
var s="may the force";
```

and I just want the `the force` part,
in python I can just do `s[4:]`, so are there 
any **equivalents** in javascript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
var s = "may the force";
var t = s.substring(4);

alert(t); //alerts "the force"
```

Check this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SiCurious/YDV65/)

Comment: No worries :) If this answer has helped, can you mark it as "Accepted"? It will be much appreciated! Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) or [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

```
//substr
var tf1 = s.substr(4);

//substring
var tf2 = s.substring(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
var s = "may the force";
var res = s.slice(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the newest implementations of JavaScript, there is a similar shorthand notation, but be warned, it is *not yet cross-browser compatible*, as it is only supported in browsers with the newest implementations of JavaScript.

```
var s = 'happy';
s[3]; // "p"
```

I came across this on the **Mozilla Developer Network** while browsing. Wish I saved the link.

Comment: I realize after re-reading that this doesn't actually solve the problem, since this only outputs a single letter rather than the trailing text, but since this answers the part of the similar python notation (and since its a cool bit of info) I'll leave it up.